# How to efficiently replace characters in a String

Tags: java, string

I have a string like this:

```
String line="[x1,x2,x3]";
```

I want to remove both of the square brackets from the String (replace them with an empty string). I tried it like this:

```
 String x=line.replace("[","").replace("]","");
```

Is there a more efficient way than this?

Comment: what's wrong with your current solution ? Although, you could shrink it up to one line.

Comment: That's looks like the empty string rather than `null` - please clarify. `x=line.replaceAll("^\\[|\\]$", "")`.

Comment: Are your brackets always at the beginning and end of the string like that? Are they always present?

Comment: brackets are always at the beginning and end of the String

Comment: @Navoda and are they always present? And is this the only place they appear?

Answer (score 2):

You may use `.replaceAll` if you want to use a regex to remove both `[` and `]` at the same time **anywhere inside the string** (actually, the equivalent of OP two line code snippet):

```
String x = line.replaceAll("[\\]\\[]+", "");
```

The `[\]\[]+` pattern matches one or more (`+`) `[` or `]` characters (these must be escaped inside `[....]`, a character class).

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/ojVKIH):

```
String line="[x1,x2,x3]";
String x = line.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]+", "");
System.out.println(x);
// => x1,x2,x3
```

Answer (score 2):

String is immutable so you can

```
String x = line.replace("[","").replace("]","");
```

another more efficient way is using regex with a pattern for both **[** and **]**

like

```
String x = line.replaceAll("[\\]\\[]+", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

If the brackets are always present, and always at the start and end of the string as shown in the example, you can just use `substring`:

```
String x2 = line.substring(1, line.length()-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
line = line.substring(1, line.length()-1);
```

---

If you want to preserve the square brackets that comes in between, then you can use:

```
String line="[x1,[x2],x3]";
line = line.replaceAll("^\\[(.*)\\]$", "$1");
```

Output

```
x1,[x2],x3
```

Answer (score 0):

If brackets can only appear at the beginning and at the end of the string, the fastest method (in terms of performance) would be using `substring` which does not involve regular expressions.

If brackets are guaranteed to be present:

```
line = line.substring(1, line.length()-1);
```

If brackets are optional:

```
int len = line.length();
int trimStart = (len > 0 && line.charAt(0) == '[') ? 1 : 0;
int trimEnd = (len > 0 && line.charAt(len-1) == ']') ? 1 : 0;
if (trimStart > 0 || trimEnd > 0) {
    line = line.substring(trimStart, len - trimEnd);
}
```